# How can I bold HTML text in an array using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have this small piece of code

```
<?php 
     foreach ($options['attributes_info'] as $attribute) : 
?>
<?php 
         echo '<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;' .
              $this->getPdfHelper()->fixEncoding(
                  $attribute['label'] . ': ' . $attribute['value']
              ) 
?>  
<?php 
     endforeach; 
?>
```

How can I bold (HTML tag `<b>`) the `'value'` that is echoed?

Comment: Thank you for the improvement Luke

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 <?php foreach ($options['attributes_info'] as $attribute) : ?>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;<?= $this->getPdfHelper()->fixEncoding($attribute['label']) ?> : <b><?= $this->getPdfHelper($attribute['value']) ?></b>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! :) I am still learning the basics, so thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Dewstar Good answer. You should explain what you changed and why you changed it.

Comment: I changed the php echo to <?= ?> (short tags) some people think it is more obvious than writing the echo and also split up the function call into two calls because the variable itself needs to be escaped and not the whole string. When you do it that way you can wrap the <b> tag around it. And thats all I did...

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap the text with the  tag.

```
<p><b>This text is bold</b>.</p>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp

Answer (score 2):

You can simply surround it with the tag:

```
'<b>' . $attribute['value'] . '</b>'
```